# Use number of downloaded file in wget as variable in bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, internet, wget

Can I get the number of downloaded files with `wget -r` and use that as a variable? I want to write a script that runs multiple wget commands in it (using -q so i can control output) and then at the end, add up the number of downloaded files and echo that to the user. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build on Jed's suggestion and take it the rest of the way, you could do something like this:

```
MY_VARIABLE=$(wget -r http://foo 2>&1 | grep -c 'saved')
```

Or, if you wanted to go a touch more complicated, but more reliable and robust, you could pull out the download count given as the summary by wget:

```
MY_VARIABLE=$(wget -r -nv http://foo 2>&1 | awk '/^Downloaded:/ {print $2}')
```

**Update:** Regarding the `2>&1` construct, for a *nix application, there are two default output streams, `stdout` (file descriptor 1) and `stderr` (file descriptor 2).  For interactive commands, both are typically sent to the screen/terminal, so it can be hard to differentiate them.  The `2>&1` tells your bash to take the output sent to `stderr` (fd 2) and combine it with the output for `stdout` (fd 1).  The result is a single output stream, which would look to the next tool in a pipe (as above) the same as the output looks to your screen.

This is required because wget defaults to sending it's status information to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  If you ran the above without the `stderr` redirection, you're sending `stdout` to the piped program, but that's all.  You'd get all of wget's output sent to your screen (`stderr`), and the variable would be empty, because the `grep` or `awk` statements are processing `stdout` (which got no output).

To see what gets sent where for an application, you can do something like this:

```
wget -r -nv http://foo 2>foo.err 1>foo.out
```

Or just:

```
wget -r -nv http://foo 2>foo.err >foo.out
```

If you don't specify a number for output redirection, it defaults to `stdout`.

The files `foo.err` and `foo.out` will contain the contents of whatever your commands end to `stderr` and `stdout`, respectively.

Also worth noting, you can also use `|&` as your pipe command to combine `stderr` with `stdout`, as a shorthand for `2>&1`.

For a little more information on the command redirection and `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`, see the bash man page, the stdin, stdout, and stderr man pages, and for historical reasons behind `stdout` and `stderr`, see this posting: http://jstorimer.com/2011/12/29/the-difference-between-stdout-and-stderr.html

Comment: could you explain the 2>&1 to me, something seems to be giving me some grief still and i think it may be this

Comment: I ran out of space in the comments to fully clarify, so I'm updating the answer to include the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply direct all the output to a file with the `-a` flag to send output to a file, then grep the logfile and count the occurrences of the word "saved":

```
root@demo:tmp# wget -r http://www.google.com/index.html -a logfile
root@demo:tmp# grep saved logfile |wc -l
1
```